# Laravel Backpack - Impersonate Operation

Tags: laravel-backpack

Im trying to create an impersonate operation within my user controller, I have been following this guide..

[impersonate for backpack](https://backpackforlaravel.com/articles/tutorials/how-to-add-impersonate-functionality-to-your-admin-panel)

The setupImpersonateDefaults function gets called ok but i get a 404 error, after some testing i figured out the setupImpersonateRoutes is not getting triggered

Any ideas on why?

> 

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Operations;

use Backpack\CRUD\app\Library\CrudPanel\CrudPanelFacade as CRUD;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Session;
use Alert;

trait ImpersonateOperation
{
    /**
     * Define which routes are needed for this operation.
     *
     * @param string $segment    Name of the current entity (singular). Used as first URL segment.
     * @param string $routeName  Prefix of the route name.
     * @param string $controller Name of the current CrudController.
     */
    protected function setupImpersonateRoutes($segment, $routeName, $controller)
    {

        Route::get($segment.'/{id}/impersonate', [
            'as'        => $routeName.'.impersonate',
            'uses'      => $controller.'@impersonate',
            'operation' => 'impersonate',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Add the default settings, buttons, etc that this operation needs.
     */
    protected function setupImpersonateDefaults()
    {


        CRUD::allowAccess('impersonate');

        CRUD::operation('impersonate', function () {
            CRUD::loadDefaultOperationSettingsFromConfig();
        });

        CRUD::operation('list', function () {
            // CRUD::addButton('top', 'impersonate', 'view', 'crud::buttons.impersonate');
            CRUD::addButton('line', 'impersonate', 'view', 'crud::buttons.impersonate');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Show the view for performing the operation.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function impersonate()
    {
        CRUD::hasAccessOrFail('impersonate');

        // prepare the fields you need to show
        $this->data['crud'] = $this->crud;
        $this->data['title'] = CRUD::getTitle() ?? 'Impersonate '.$this->crud->entity_name;

        $entry = $this->crud->getCurrentEntry();

        backpack_user()->setImpersonating($entry->id);

        Alert::success('Impersonating '.$entry->name.' (id '.$entry->id.').')->flash();

        // load the view
        return redirect('dashboard');

        // load the view
        //return view('crud::operations.impersonate', $this->data);
    }
}
```

Have tried following the guides and the routes are not getting added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for anyone else looking at this, you need to call the route from the \routes\backpack\custom.php file, if its not called from this file it wont trigger the setupXXXRoute function

Answer (score 0):

One of the official Backpack team members has created an add-on for impersonating users. You can use his add-on or get inspiration from it:

https://github.com/maurohmartinez/impersonate-users-backpack-laravel